# Halo freehub body 10 teeth need part number or correct description

Tags: freewheel, rear-wheel, freehub, halo

Hi all you've been all helpful so far, I need to order one of these, please see attached pic:

It is a hub part from HALO COMBAT wheel 10 teeth, I cannot find correct part number or description, I need to order one ASAP. Could someone help me please?

[image: ten teeth hub from halo combat wheel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that wheel was laced to a Halo rear hub, here's where to look for the hub model:  Look edge on around the spoke flange. The outer circumference of one of the spoke flanges of the rear wheel.  Stamped there on a Halo hub will be multiple  digit, alpha-numeric code.

[image: Halo hub code]

Once recorded, go to the Halo website and via the menu, select "support" then select "Tech/FAQ." Scan the results to find, "Which Halo hub do I have?" It is there you will find a listing of alpha-numeric codes representing the hub model. Compare the listings to the code you recorded from your rear Halo hub from whence the freehub body in your photo came. Match the code and you'll have the correct replacement.  Any problems with that, and if you're sure it's a Halo hub,  utilize the "contact us" menu option to discuss with a Halo agent.

It appears you may be showing an RLSS hub body. Like this one, perhaps?

[image: rlss]